# Unknown files in /tmp folder

Tags: 18.04, systemd

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTE.  I have recently found that there are some files that are auto created in the `/tmp` folder.

```
config-err-b3hxSF
ssh-gZzvdo1vMa0c
systemd-private-d1c888875ba144018c45bd96a98acd3e-bolt.service-0hkC6S
systemd-private-d1c888875ba144018c45bd96a98acd3e-colord.service-T8w2yE
systemd-private-d1c888875ba144018c45bd96a98acd3e-ModemManager.service-K2jqXo
systemd-private-d1c888875ba144018c45bd96a98acd3e-rtkit-daemon.service-gmm9I0
systemd-private-d1c888875ba144018c45bd96a98acd3e-systemd-hostnamed.service-PH7uGs
systemd-private-d1c888875ba144018c45bd96a98acd3e-systemd-localed.service-vVpIvh
systemd-private-d1c888875ba144018c45bd96a98acd3e-systemd-resolved.service-N9Ti2D
systemd-private-d1c888875ba144018c45bd96a98acd3e-systemd-timesyncd.service-NDRJUb
```

I am not sure what these folder/files are.  They are mostly empty. If I use, `Microsoft Teams`, I get some additional files.

Is this good or bad?

Can anyone help me in this regard.

**UPDATE**

1. I am not sure about Systemd other than reading jokes about it in
   Reddit.
2. There are two folders for `net` and `ssh` namely `net-export` and
   `ssh-hJ9Bd4cVFGor`. The first folder is empty, while the second   one is having a file `agent.1454`. Recently, I started using a private fiber optic network using wi-fi.
3. I have a folder `babel-q0yHwG` which is also empty.
4. When I use, `Microsoft Teams` folders are created for `G8 Engine`.
5. Sometime, when a click a link to open a new location, a totally
   unwanted location is coming up.
6. Other than that, I have Emacs temporary files, which I can
   understand.

Since these days, due to security concerns, I am a bit afraid as these folders were not created earlier.  Most of the time, this folder remained empty unless when I open a PDF file in the browser.
Hope I am able to clarify.

Comment: The `/tmp` directory is used for temporary files and the names given are usually random to ensure applications don’t overwrite existing files used by other instances. This directory is often cleaned out during reboot 

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I have tried to explain my doubts as far as possible.  Hope this will be enough for you to help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Various applications use the `/tmp` folder to store temporary information. On Ubuntu and many other linux distributions, this directory is cleaned between reboots. So there is no need for you to worry about this folder.

Comment: Still I have a doubt for many reasons. First, I am using Microsoft Teams (I always doubt MS). Then, this systemd. I am not sure about this.

Comment: You will need to explicitly state "your many reasons" why you have doubt in your question. Please edit and elaborate on your doubts if this answer is not good for you.